# How can I turn a text area into an input stream in java?

Tags: java, swing, io, console, jtextpane

I'm trying to make a Java port of some C++ code in a book I have, and the book uses some OS specific stuff to color text in the console window.

I decided that because there is no easy way of getting that to work cross platform in java, I could make a window with a text area that would emulate a console.  Printing and coloring text is simple, but I can't figure out how to get the input stream part of a console working.

I want the object returned by my Console.getIn() method to work exactly like System.in does.  My current code sorta works, but will hang if used as the input to a Scanner.  I've listed my implementation below, please let me know if you can tell what is wrong with my code or if there is a better way to do this.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

/**
 *
 * @author William Matrix Peckham
 */
public class Console extends JTextPane {

    DocOutputStream out;
    PrintStream pout;
    DocInputStream in;
    JFrame frame;
    StyledDocument doc;



    public Console() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        doc = this.getStyledDocument();
        out = new DocOutputStream(doc,this);
        pout=new PrintStream(out);
        in = new DocInputStream();
        this.addKeyListener(in);
        setFGColor(Color.black);
        setBGColor(Color.white);
        frame = new JFrame("Console");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(this));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public InputStream getIn(){
        return in;
    }
    public PrintStream getOut(){
        return pout;
    }

    public void setFGColor(Color c){
        StyleConstants.setForeground(out.cur, c);
    }
    public void setBGColor(Color c){
        StyleConstants.setBackground(out.cur, c);
    }

    private static class DocOutputStream extends OutputStream {

        StyledDocument doc;
        MutableAttributeSet cur;
        JTextPane pane;

        public DocOutputStream(StyledDocument doc, JTextPane pane) {
            this.doc = doc;
            this.pane=pane;
            cur=new SimpleAttributeSet();
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            try {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), (char)b+"", cur);
                pane.setCaretPosition(doc.getLength());
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Console.class.getName()).
                        log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

    private static class DocInputStream extends InputStream implements KeyListener {

        ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

        public DocInputStream(){
            queue=new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1024);
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            Integer i=null;
            try {
                i = queue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Console.class.getName()).
                        log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if(i!=null)
                return i;
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int c = e.getKeyCode();
            try {
                queue.put(c);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Console.class.getName()).
                        log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Edit: note that in read() I tried poll() instead of take(), which stopped it from blocking at all, but I thought it may stop Scanner from blocking forever which was true, but it also stopped it from getting any real input at all.

Comment: Use a JTextPane, it supports a StyledDocument

Comment: The code in the question already is using it, the coloring and output isn't the question, it's making the pane work like System.in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  The problem was that Scanner was calling InputStream.read(char[],int,int), which is implemented to read the whole stream or the entire sized buffer.  The scanner was attempting to fill a buffer of 8000+ bytes, and the default read(...) implementation stops calls read() only after the buffer is full, or -1 is read (EOF).

This lead the scanner to block forever, because most console input would never be that long. The solution was to override the buffered read. The version I need will block for the first byte, and return if there are no more characters, I thought the BufferedInputStream already implemented this by calling available() on the stream, so I tried wrapping my class in one after overriding available and that did not work.  My new implementation uses available() as well as EOF as a stopping case.

This is what the implementation now looks like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

/**
 *
 * @author William Matrix Peckham
 */
public class Console extends JTextPane {

    DocOutputStream out;
    PrintStream pout;
    DocInputStream in;
    JFrame frame;
    StyledDocument doc;



    public Console() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        doc = this.getStyledDocument();
        out = new DocOutputStream(doc,this);
        pout=new PrintStream(out);
        in = new DocInputStream();
        this.addKeyListener(in);
        setFGColor(Color.black);
        setBGColor(Color.white);
        frame = new JFrame("Console");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(this));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public InputStream getIn(){
        return in;
    }
    public PrintStream getOut(){
        return pout;
    }

    public void setFGColor(Color c){
        StyleConstants.setForeground(out.cur, c);
    }
    public void setBGColor(Color c){
        StyleConstants.setBackground(out.cur, c);
    }

    private static class DocOutputStream extends OutputStream {

        StyledDocument doc;
        MutableAttributeSet cur;
        JTextPane pane;

        public DocOutputStream(StyledDocument doc, JTextPane pane) {
            this.doc = doc;
            this.pane=pane;
            cur=new SimpleAttributeSet();
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            try {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), (char)b+"", cur);
                pane.setCaretPosition(doc.getLength());
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Console.class.getName()).
                        log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

    private static class DocInputStream extends InputStream implements KeyListener {

        ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

        public DocInputStream(){
            queue=new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1024);
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            Integer i=null;
            try {
                i = queue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Console.class.getName()).
                        log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if(i!=null)
                return i;
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            if (b == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            } else if (off < 0 || len < 0 || len > b.length - off) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            } else if (len == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
                    int c = read();
            if (c == -1) {
                return -1;
            }
            b[off] = (byte)c;

            int i = 1;
            try {
                for (; i < len && available() > 0 ; i++) {
                    c = read();
                    if (c == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    b[off + i] = (byte)c;
                }
            } catch (IOException ee) {
            }   
            return i;

        }



        @Override
        public int available(){
            return queue.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            int c = e.getKeyChar();
            try {
                queue.put(c);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Console.class.getName()).
                        log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code and things seem well-enough set up that `keyTyped` is invoked while the app is "idle" (i.e., no read is pending) when I press keys in the appropriate `JTextPane`. When I try to `read` from the program (either a single byte directly from a stream, or a line from a `Scanner` tied to the stream) it blocks on the `queue.take()` invocation—in spite of subsequent input. Moreover, keystrokes are no longer dispatched to `keyTyped`. Am I blocking the entire program? Do you have another thread running that's allowing the character input to go to the handler and unblock the queue?

Comment: I haven't come across this issue, are you calling the scanner/read() methods from the GUI thread? My code uses no extra threads other than the EDT, If you call read() or scanner methods from the EDT it will block forever because it is waiting for keyTyped to add a character, but the EDT is blocked and won't dispatch new events.  My intended use case for this was as a drop-in replacement for a command prompt for console apps that needed coloring. to use it with a GUI you need to make sure your read calls are NOT on the event dispatch thread.

Comment: That's what I thought; thanks. This takes me to the limits of my Java experience but I'm willing to learn. Is it conventional to provide a separate thread for the console? So far I've not needed it.... I have a JEdtiorPane and then a JTextPane for console output; I also want to use the JTextPane for console input. I'm achieving output synchronization w/o the using an extra thread, i.e., using `textComponent.update(textComponent.getGraphics())`. Do I get GUI events on a separate thread by putting its entire initialization inside a `Runnable`? Pointers where I can learn? Thanks.

Comment: I've never tried it, but I don't think so. My understanding is that the JVM will always put all GUIs on one thread that it controls.  I'm not sure what you mean about using update(). If you show the code where your calling read()/scanner methods, like the handler you call it from I could try to help you find a work-around. First thought: use an excecutor, and a callable and a Swing timer http://pastebin.com/YLw7VVq8 it probably won't compile and needs extra imports was written from memory but should serve the purpose you need, with more of your code I could probably do something simpler though

Comment: So I had to learn a lot... but think I've made it up the learning curve and now have code that soundly limps along... It's online at GitHub. The threading code is around line 611 in https://github.com/jcoplien/trygve/blob/master/src/main/java/info/fulloo/trygve/editor/TextEditorGUI.java; the meat is in https://github.com/jcoplien/trygve/blob/master/src/main/java/info/fulloo/trygve/editor/MessageConsole.java. For line input I had to add line controls (^H & ^U), echoing, and CR/LF translation to make the line recognition pattern matcher happy in Scanner.findWithinHorizon. Tx for you help!

Comment: hm, your addition of cr/lf and backspace handling made me test something, and it appears my code, and by extension, yours, has an issue, if the user moves the insertion point and deletes something in the middle, a scanner and I believe your backspace handling code will delete the end of the input and not the middle. I only ever intended to use this code for a side project, but I may revise it. You may want to look into that if you intend to have a well-behaved console. Also I didn't think of SwingWorker, That's much cleaner than the ad-hoc pastebin I did.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [Message Console](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) will work for your requirements. You can use a JTextArea or JTextPane as the console component.

Comment: My current code already does can do output, I want to know how to make it act like System.in as well as out.  Your link does not appear to support input, and neither do any console classes I have been able to find.